# Vertical barchart using Android Graphview

Tags: android, android-graphview

Is it possible to create a vertical bar chart using GraphView in android.?

```
       GraphView graph = (GraphView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.graph);
    BarGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new BarGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[] {
            new DataPoint(0, -2),
            new DataPoint(1, 5),
            new DataPoint(2, 3),
            new DataPoint(3, 2),
            new DataPoint(4, 6)
    });
    graph.addSeries(series);

    // legend
    series.setTitle("foo");

    graph.getLegendRenderer().setVisible(true);
    graph.getLegendRenderer().setAlign(LegendRenderer.LegendAlign.TOP);
```

Comment: not possible at the moment out of the box